# Is there a way in angularjs to share real-time information between two open tabs

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

We Need to make an angularjs web with a login page where user login.

Then this page  get information about logged user from the server to use later.

When user is ok logged an informative message show say something like : 'You are logged susccessfully, do not close'

Same angular web must have other pages a user can load. 
For example pages with a lots of lists of information from back-end (but for get this information we can use data from the logged user tab still open).

But if user is not logged or user close the login page (we mean the page  with susccessfully logged message) all opened tabs with pages listing information must close or show message of 'sorry, not logged, you closed session'.

We use angular routing for differents pages in an angular app but  How can we connect all tabs so get information from a unique page of login and how close all of them if user is not loged or close login page in firts tab.?

Comment: you can use $rootscope or service to save logged in data and check in you angular template whether to show data or not.

Comment: Thank you, but problem is there may be several separate tabs open and if we close loggin tab all other  tabs must close. We have thought of localstorage, but are there other ways to do this, angularjs have better tools for this?

Comment: First thing which comes in my mind is to add listener on Local Storage. However you should consider to use websockets or real time frameworks on server side to communicate with a client. So that could work event on different machines.

Comment: Thanks Brivvirs, localstorage was our idea too. As far as We know is an APP on only one mahine, where a user login. Not need of controls sessions on diferentes machines only differents browsers native tabs. 

So for now localstorage is the only solution, there is nothing in angularjs to help this.

Comment: The need of  browser tabs is a mustbe here because the especifications of how users are going to use this web. We are not allowed to use simulated tabs by design and programming as the case of material design, we must think of native tabs of the browser. Really equivalent to different windows of the same web development